# Cast an object with Type T to Type T<System.Guid>

Tags: c#, properties, dynamic-typing

I inherited a project with a Windows mobile part. To make a long story short, my problem is this:

```
[DBPropertyUpdate("CustomerId")]
[DBPropertyRetrieve("CustomerId")]
public CustomerBase<T> Customer
{
    get { return _customer; }
    set { _customer = SetProperty(_customer, value); }
}
```

throws an exception.

In a watch window I have the following:

```
> NAME         VALUE                           TYPE

_customer   {Pss.Common.Mia.Customer}   Pss.Common.Mia.CustomerBase<System.Guid> {Pss.Common.Mia.Customer}
(Pss.Common.Mia.CustomerBase<System.Guid>)_customer Cannot convert type 'Pss.Common.Mia.CustomerBase<T>' to 'Pss.Common.Mia.CustomerBase<System.Guid>'
```

I am not familiar with this code, but was hoping there would be some easy way to convert `'Pss.Common.Mia.CustomerBase<T>' to 'Pss.Common.Mia.CustomerBase<System.Guid>'`
The seconcd Watch entry was my attemp, which as you can see fails.

Comment: What is _customer defined as? I don't think we've got enough there to give you a full answer...

Comment: _customer =  {Pss.Common.Mia.Customer}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable _customer typed as CustomerBase<Guid> cannot possibly be cast to CustomerBase<T> since T is not known. You must also type _customer as CustomerBase<T> for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by passing `CustomerBase<Guid>` as type to the function which builds the customer object